# I am looking for a set of user stories that are used in actual projects

Tags: user-stories

I am looking for a real world example of user stories (I.e. one that is/has been used for an actual project) does anyone know where i could find a set of user stories? there needs to be at least 50+ stories. The project nature is not relevant. Any links would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

A question from which I can certainly understand that you are new to Agile working.!
A Good User Story is Any Problem/issue which can be written in a simple form so that:

- it is easy to read (simple language)
- anybody can understand the wordings.
- it must have the basic data to start developing it to reality.

Example:

if you want to create a login screen for your new website, as a Product owner I would write my story as below:

> As a website User, I would like to see the login screen with
>
> a UserID input and a password input field
>
> And It should have a "forgot password" functionality to work with a registered email ID.

The above is very simple story, There could be at times a Multi factor authentication or any simple authentication can be used in the login process.

A User Story is the Users need basically. If the user expresses to have an authentication, then yes it can be added to the story. not all users know how a login works, what is generally known is a ID and password and forgot password

Hope this helps:
more information refer:
https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories
There are some real example of user stories which you can download as a pdf ..!

Hope this helps.!

Comment: Isn't this example story a bit leading? I would expect that user might express a need to authenticate themself in order to prevent others to access their content (for instance).

Comment: @OndrejK. yes, User Story is something what the user actually wants, if user feels an authentication is required, then yes go for it in the story, ut certain technical processes the user may not know, like in ,y experience many users dont know how the login works, so the Scrum team needs to discuss and brainstorm how serious the website is, what security is requires and others.!